# Fiat Uno 1100 fire does not start

Tags: uno

I have a Fiat Uno 1100 fire that does not start. After a time of struggling it starts but then I must hold it so it can stay started and when it is started it does not want to do nothing just hooooooooo. It does not want to rev nothing. New distributor and mogole and new petrol pump.

Comment: What is a "mogole" ? Have you set the timing correctly when you fitted the new distributor? If you don't have the correct timing setting - then a good starting point is usually 5 degrees before...

Comment: Could that be the word: Module  ?

Comment: Yes sorry it is a module. The timing is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Check compression. Maybe head gasket is blown.